# How to access memory dynamically without using dynamic allocator include the brk, sbrk and mmap

Tags: c

I have been given a task to simulate heap space and implement `malloc`, `free` and `realloc` on this piece of memory. The size of this piece of memory is not fixed, but I am not allowed to use any standard library allocator, `brk`, `sbrk`, `mmap`, `alloca`, and variable-length array.
Can anybody give me even a piece of hint on this?

Thanks for you guys but static variables are also forbidden.

Comment: Use a static array. You're not really given any other option.

Comment: Maybe you should interface directly with the OS? Or is this also not allowed, in which case @EmanuelP's comment is a good approach.

Comment: To me it sounds as if you have misunderstood the task. I think that you are supposed to use one big static (aka file scope global) array of memory. Then your `malloc` will give the program a little part of that memory and `free` will return it to you. You'll have to implement the housekeeping stuff to control which parts are free and which parts are in use.

Comment: @Devolus. `brk` and `mmap` are the way to interface with the OS. They are system calls. I think the point of the exercise is merely to write an implementation of `malloc` given some arbitrary address space.

Comment: @EmanuelP I meant that he might have to write his own syscalls, instead of using `brk` or others. The requirement that the memory size is not fixed, doesn't sound like a static array.

Comment: @Devolus True, but I suspect what is meant by that is the `malloc` and related are to be written in a way that they are independent of the size of the available memory. It is after all, to *simulate* a heap.

Comment: Thanks for you guys but static variables are also forbidden.

Comment: Then you need to ask your professor exactly where this memory is supposed to come from.

Comment: @Devolus: There would be little point in an assignment to write a memory allocator that must write its own system calls. If one is teaching a student to how to implement system calls using assembly or other means, one gives them an assignment directly for that, such as “Write requests to the system routines `open` and `write` using inline assembly and the trap instruction [or whatever is suitable for the architecture being used],” not as an assignment to write a memory allocator with a constraint about not using `brk`.

Comment: Show the exact wording of the assignment. The description in the question is inadequate.

Comment: In this assignment, your allocator will manage a virtualised heap using a function we provide that simulates using brk to
manipulate a real process heap. When dynamic memory is requested from your allocator, it will allocate it from this virtual “heap

Comment: In this assignment you will be implementing a simple dynamic memory allocator with a similar interface to the standard
libary functions (such as malloc) that you are familiar with.
You will be implementing your allocator as a library of functions that can be called by other programs, rather than as a
standalone executable.

Comment: No other restriction except given

Comment: OK, so you'll be provided a function to call that will give you memory.  Then you can call that function instead of `brk`.  For testing, create your own definition of that function that just calls `malloc`, then you can later replace it with the provided function.

Comment: @dbush Thanks a lot, since there is something ambiguous in the scaffold given that I have not recognized this point (this brk replacement function is in another file rather than our implementation and not declared in header files, it turns out that we need to declare it by ourselves). :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation is that you are supposed to write an implementation on a *simulated* heap. That is, you should write code that allows the user to allocate and deallocate address space. The memory does not physically have to be available, but your code should act *as if* it manages heap space of some arbitrary size.

Comment: Appreciate it, but if that is true, they will not need to highlight that those standard allocators were forbidden.

Comment: @skankhunt76 Judging from your latest comment, this is the case. You will be given a "virtual heap" and you need to manage that "virtual heap". You can write your code using `brk` because you are given a function that replaces this.

Comment: Thanks, the given scaffold was misleading me that I thought I am not supposed to use that function in my own implementation :D